# mysql trigger to calculate elapsed minutes

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with *start_date* and *end_date* both datetime type.
I need a trigger that calculate the elapsed minutes between both dates and update the result on the *duration* field on the same table when the end_date is updated.

For some reason all I try gives me Syntax error.
I'm using phpMyAdmin sql window to do it.

Please help.

Comment: Will this trigger be fired on INSERT or on UPDATE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'my_trigger'
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.end_date IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET NEW.duration  = (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NEW.end_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.start_date)) / 60
END IF;

END //
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know what am I doing wrong, but I always get syntax error, no matter is the simplest statement. I tried your code and get error as well... - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 8

Comment: Dont forget to set it as an answer if it was your answer that you were looking for. Hope you manage your trigger. GoodLuck !